# Dataproc on GKE: python packages listed in properties not installed

Tags: pyspark, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a dataproc cluster on a GKE cluster. The required packages already included inside the properties like examples in [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration). But when I submitted a job, it failed with an error: ModuleNotFoundError.

```
...
Waiting for job output...
 PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/conda/bin/python
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-8-jdk-amd64
SPARK_EXTRA_CLASSPATH=
Merging Spark configs
Skipping merging /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf, file does not exist.
Skipping merging /opt/spark/conf/log4j.properties, file does not exist.
Skipping merging /opt/spark/conf/spark-env.sh, file does not exist.
Skipping custom init script, file does not exist.
Running heartbeat loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-d6516b57-0924-4ce2-9de8-a5c1116667b4/pkg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.cloud import secretmanager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

This is the gcloud command I used:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters gke create gke-dp --region=asia-southeast1 --spark-engine-version=3.1 \
--gke-cluster=gke-spark --gke-cluster-location=asia-southeast1-b --namespace=dataproc \
--pools='name=dp-default,roles=default,machineType=n2-standard-2,min=1,max=1' \
--pools='name=dp-workers,roles=spark-driver;spark-executor,machineType=n2-standard-4,min=1,max=4' \
--properties='^#^dataproc:pip.packages=google-cloud-secret-manager==2.15.0,numpy==1.24.1#spark:spark.jars=https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.5.1.jar' \
--properties="dataproc:dataproc.gke.agent.google-service-account=dataproc@de-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--properties="dataproc:dataproc.gke.spark.driver.google-service-account=dataproc@de-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--properties="dataproc:dataproc.gke.spark.executor.google-service-account=dataproc@de-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have installed `google-cloud` using this command  `pip install  google-cloud`.

Comment: The doc is for Dataproc on GCE only https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration You need to create a custom container image to include Python packages https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dpgke/dataproc-gke-custom-images

Comment: @Dagang so it's not possible using `properties` to install python packages in GKE dataproc cluster. is a custom image the only way to install them? I recall with dataproc on GCE there are few other ways other than cluster properties and custom iamge, such as init action script and metadata. would they not work for dataproc on GKE ?

Comment: AFAIK, custom image is the only option for DP on GKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not supported by Dataproc on GKE.